# How to install .tar.gz lacking both ./configure and ./bin?

Tags: 20.04, software-installation

I want to install Chaotica https://www.chaoticafractals.com/download on Ubuntu 20.04.2.
It does not contain an installation instruction. There is a README, but it contains only license and thanks, nothing on installation or launching.

I've found several instructions for using tarballs with ./configure and make, but the unpacked folder does not contain a ./configure file.
Then I found instructions using bin, but there is neither a bin folder nor a bin file in the unpacked tar.
Are there other ways to install?
Thanks!

Comment: Maye it would be better asking on their forum on the website.

Comment: The tar file is labelled on their site as "Archive", opposite to "Installer" that you have for example for Windows and MacOS version. So no installation at all - simply unpack to any directory and run.

Comment: @SorenA I've tried, but no answer.

Answer (score 4):

On Microsoft Windows such applications are called portable.

So you can simply download the archive and then run main executable as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c https://www.chaoticafractals.com/dist/chaotica_x64_v2.0.36.tar.gz
tar -xf chaotica_x64_v2.0.36.tar.gz
cd chaotica_x64_v2.0.36
./chaotica
```

If you want to install it to, for example, `/opt`, then use commands below:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/chaotica
sudo cp -ar ~/Downloads/chaotica_x64_v2.0.36/* /opt/chaotica
sudo ln -s /opt/chaotica/chaotica /usr/local/bin/chaotica
```

And finally create desktop-file for it:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/icons
cd ~/.local/share/icons
wget https://www.chaoticafractals.com/sites/all/themes/chaotica/favicon.ico -O chaotica.ico

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications/
cd ~/.local/share/applications/

cat <<EOF > chaotica.desktop # copy from this line to EOF, then paste
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Icon=/home/$USER/.local/share/icons/chaotica.ico
Exec=chaotica
Name=Chaotica
EOF
```

and then launch it from dash/menu.

Comment: if you don't like the command line, you can presumably also just [double-]click on the file "chaotica" in the file browser to run it.

Comment: @user253751 I've tried that (with and without executable bit) and it does not work. It asks with which application I want to open chaotica.

Comment: @N0rbert haven't had time to try, but looks very promising!